# replace space for every string in the list

Tags: c#

I am trying to renaming every file's empty space with an underscore:

```
DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(@"Q:\Audio");
var files = (from f in dir.GetFiles() select f.FullName);
files.ToList().ConvertAll( s => s.Replace( " ", "_") );
```

But it's not working, I tried to use a foreach loop and it complains "Cannot assign to 'element' because it is a 'foreach iteration variable'"

How do I approach this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use one of code blocks below:

```
DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\");
var files = (from f in dir.GetFiles() select f.FullName.Replace(" ", "_"));
```

or:

```
DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\");
var files = (from f in dir.GetFiles() select f.FullName);
var fileNames = (from fn in files select fn.Replace(" ", "_"));
```

or:

```
DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\");
var files = (from f in dir.GetFiles() select f.FullName);
var fileNames = files.Select(s => s.Replace(" ", "_"));
```

or (Bad Idea):

```
DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\");
var files = (from f in dir.GetFiles() select f.FullName);
var fileNames = files.ToList().ConvertAll(s => s.Replace(" ", "_"));
```

EDIT 1:
 but i suggest to use select function, its better to not call .ToList() method for deferred objects like IQueryable.

Answer (score 4):

`ConvertAll` returns a new `List`.

```
var renamedFiles = files.ToList().ConvertAll(s => s.Replace(" ", "_"));
```

Answer (score 0):

you actually need to reset your variable `files`.   Change you last line to reset the `files` variable with the output from `ConvertAll`.

```
files = files.ToList().ConvertAll( s => s.Replace( " ", "_") );
```